# .NET WebClient SSL handshake missing user-agent and SessionID

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, webclient, tls1.2

I'm using WebClient to call a remote API via HTTPS.
The initial CONNECT (before the GET) is missing the User-Agent information. I already tried to add it by overriding WebClient GetWebRequest function but it still does not send the User-Agent for the CONNECT.

Any idea how to include it?
Please note that this is for the CONNECT, which happens before the GET.

I also noticed that SessionID is empty, which is different then when connecting directly through Chrome for example.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: "The initial CONNECT"? From where did you get that name? Do you refer to SSL handshake? `User-Agent` and other headers is part of HTTP protocol, so it won't appear in SSL packets.

Comment: Or are you talking about the CONNECT request which is used when a proxy is involved? No user agent is needed here and there is no such thing as a session at this stage.

Comment: @LexLi In my Fiddler, it shows a CONNECT before the GET, where the SSL handshake happens. Both IE and Chrome have User-Agent for the CONNECT, and ideally I wanted to do the same when using WebClient.